# Assembly Comparing variables from incloud file

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am building a assembly Ai in TicTacToe game. And I am using eu8086 emuolator.
my idea was simple i preaped a table.

```
table db 0 0 0
      db 0 0 0
      db 0 0 0
```

and change the value every time the player was playing.
now, i created a lot of this tables every one with different state.
and compared them to the curnnet one, and then tell the computer what to do.
so i made incloud file and put a lot of variables their the problem is that when i compared them the computer dont recongnized that the are the same, but if its in the same file he is recongnized.

CompareScript:

```
    CompareArray MACRO arr1,arr2
    cld
    mov cx,9

    lea di,arr1
    lea si,arr2

    repe cmpsb
    jnz enddd

    mov isEquel, 1
    jmp ed
enddd:
    mov isEquel,0 
ed:
    ENDM
```

How i incloud the file:

```
include TicTacToeAi.inc
```

The file itself(i delete a lot to try and check the problem):

```
; TicTacToeAi.inc - macro definitions library for easy input/output

tableF   db 1,0,0 
         db 0,0,0 
         db 0,0,0
```

I will be glad for help!!!

Comment: Please don't link images of code. Instead, just write the code here directly (like you've done with the table definitions.

Comment: Disassemble the binary file generated by your assembler (or have the assembler generate a list file). Use that output to compare the code generated with and without include file. I think that is the most reliable way to find out what is going on.

Comment: Ruud Helderman can you show me how exacly?

Comment: I never used emu8086, but I saw a [screenshot](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/COE/shazli/coe205/Help/emu8086.html) of its emulator, and it appeared to be capable of [disassembling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler) an executable.

Comment: You are probably including it in different segment than previous, and you don't reflect that by using correct segment register (`cmps` does implicitly use `ds:si` as "source" address and `es:di` as "destination" address, where the implicit `ds` can be overridden by segment prefix and the `es` is set in silicon). emu8086 did add support of listing files lately, maybe check with the SW vendor, for other assemblers it's often `-l` command line option. Anyway try to produce [MCVE] for SO, from the pieces you did post it is not clear how/where you include the data and how you set the compare code.

Comment: Also probably avoid macros if you are just learning x86, macros bring almost no advantage, but make reading and debugging of code much harder for seasoned asm developers, because it's then difficult to straight read the source code and imagine the exact output of assembler (as you would have to recall macro definitions from head). While in ordinary assembly you see every instruction upon read. The way you use your `CompareArray` macro I would categorize as abuse, should have been coded as "function/procedure" and called from main code with ordinary `call`.

Comment: Or to put it shortly: the info you posted is insufficient to answer. If I would try to write similar code on my own, it would work, using the same pieces you posted. So the problematic parts are not shown (although I find the posted parts also "problematic" due to code style vs my opinion how a well designed code should be written, but that's different level of problematic). Try to edit your question with better info, or it may get closed as "unclear what you are asking" or some other similar reason.

Comment: For example: *"How i inclode the file"* - are you aware the assembler does produce "machine code", i.e. positioning your include for example somewhere inside the code will produce data bytes which will get by accident executed as instructions? The whole assembly source is not only describing which instructions should be assembled, but also positioning them relatively in the final machine code, so you have to put each piece at proper place (some assemblers allow for quick switch between sections with directives like `.code/.data`, but more often the data can't mix with code)

Comment: Suggestion: have your macro just leave the result in ZF.  Presumably code that uses this macro is going to branch on the result, so it's much more efficient to just do `CompareArray state, [bx]` / `je match_found` without having some static storage involved for the result.  (Same thing applies if you take Ped7g's suggestion and put this in a function instead of macro.  In that case I'd suggest having the caller pass args in SI and DI, and return in ZF.  So the function body is just `cld` / `mov cx,9` / `repe cmpsb` / `ret`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you very much!!! But after doing this and trying to do what i want, i always fell problems so i wanted to ask, Do you have an idea how create ai in assembly???

Comment: I'd do it the same way I would in C, with a recursive function that tries every move and checks if any of them lead to a forced win (take that one), a draw with best play, or if the opponent can force a loss (avoid that unless all legal moves lead there.)  I had to do that in C for a first-year computer-science course about 20 years ago.  I used similar 9-byte structs like you're doing.  If I was doing it now, especially in asm, I might use a bit-board: the game state is represented by two 9-bit integers, one for each player's marks.  Check for wins with e.g. `and ax, 0b111` / `cmp ax, 0b111`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you show or send me the code? That will help me understand it better and use it myself. Thank you anyway!